# IE specific: Translate Pipe not working in Angular 2 RC4

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I am trying to use ng2-translate to show **userName** in different languages.

My **LoginComponent** looks like the one below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService, TranslatePipe} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-app',
    templateUrl: './app/components/html/login.component.html',
    pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})

export class LoginComponent {
    userName: string;

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {

        this.initializeTranslateServiceConfig();
    }

    initializeTranslateServiceConfig() {
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        this._translate.use(userLang);
    }
}
```

My template **login.component.html** has a label which displays the **userName**

```
    <label for="userName">{{"User Name" | translate}}</label>
```

I have different .json files to support the translations.

Now I am changing the language settings of Chrome, Firefox and IE11.
It works perfectly for Chrome and Firefox but not for IE11. :(

Can anybody please tell me what could be the problem and the possible solution?

Thanks,

Debopam

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation on the MSDN `navigator.userLanguage` returns the operating system's natural language, not the preferred language set in your browser. ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534713(v=vs.85).aspx))
Changing the browsers language setting will not effect this value.

Other browsers do support `navigator.language`, but also have some drawbacks, as stated on MDN, as not all will return the user's preferred language. ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language))

At work we are using a server-side API-call which returns the `Accept-Language` HTTP-Header, to identify the language(s).

Answer (score 0):

For angular2 to work on internet explorer you need to include shims package in your index.html

Download & Add the following script to your html:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Angular2 RC4. Could you please let me know to get the file as adding **"es6-shim": "0.35.1" ** in **package.json** didn't download the file for me.

Comment: you can download it externally @DebopamChanda